# Why does getting end coordinates using start coordinates, distance and angle seem to fall short?

Tags: linear-algebra

While working on a problem today related to movement of a ball on a grid I wrote these formulas:

end_x = start_x+ distance * cos( deg2rad(angle))

end_y = start_y + distance * sin( deg2rad(angle))

When it is a simple angle, it works:
start_x=0, start_y=0 angle=0, distance=10 -> end_x = 10, end_y = 0.

But if I run it and change angle to 225 (southwest) it gives me:
end_x = -7.07, end_y = -7.07, which is just under 3 coordinates short.
Because if it's traveling 10 units directly southwest, surely it ends up at -10, -10/

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Use MathJax formatting for mathematical expressions. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're program is fine. Moving a distance of $10$ in a SW direction is the same as moving $\sqrt 50$ South and $\sqrt 50$ West.

(You'll find it helps to draw a diagram and apply Pythagoras.)

Comment: Thanks for this, I suppose then to be able to work out end_x and end_y for them being exactly d distance at angle a I need a different formula? Going on as the crow flies,

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure what you mean. Moving a distance in a given direction like you have done is the usual practice.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm not understanding. Surely if I walk 10 steps southwest of a pole, then my coordinates are (pole_x-10, pole_y-10)?

Comment: No. It's exactly as given by your program. You will have gone a distance of 10 steps but you won't be as much as 10 steps away in a Southerly direction. You really should draw a diagram and measure distances if you're unsure about this.

Comment: Thanks. You're quite right I did need to draw this out and even then it took me a while to actually get it.

Comment: Glad to be of help!